# debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS in flash/iphone app

Tags: iphone, flash, apache-flex

I'm using the iPhone packager that's part of Air 2.7 (`adt -package ipa-ad-hoc ...`) for a fairly large application.  (It takes about ~30 min to run the packager.)

When the app runs on the iPhone, it will crash almost immediately-- long before it gets to my code.  The crash log shows

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc0067bdb
```

The debugging facilities included with Flash Builder only work after the app has launched-- there doesn't seem to be anything to help me figure out why its not launching.

I've been able to get toy 'hello world' apps working, but I'm stymied here.  Anyone else run into this problem?  And, if so, what did you do to diagnose it?

Comment: Does it work in the iPad emulator included as part of Flash Builder 4.5.1? Are you using the new Flash Builder, or compiling on the command line?

Comment: I'm building with both FB and the CLI and the results are the same.  Curiously it will work if I using the adl emulator or the 'Fast' Packaging method (in the Debug Configuration).  It seems to just be release builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to debug this, since its a problem with the packaging code that surrounds my code.  :(

I ended up having to track this down the hard way by 'binary searching' my code-- that is, commenting out half of it, build, see if it crashes, if not comment out the other half, etc.

It took a while, but I narrowed it down to a single line of code.  This code never gets a chance to run-- just the * presence* of this line causes the iOS app to crash on startup.  Here it is reduced to its essence:

```
public class Foo extends EventDispatcher {
    public override function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean=false, priority:int=0, useWeakReference:Boolean=false):void {
        var thisFunc:Function= arguments.callee;
        super.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
    }
}
```

Somehow `arguments.callee` is what's causing the problem.  This is otherwise valid AS3 code, so it must be a bug.  I've filed an issue with Adobe [here](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-32130).